# "This directory appears to be a Git repository" error?

Tags: git, github

I tried to submit my Github Project to my account; however, when I tried to make a new repository to commit to my Github account, I encountered the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACkWE.jpg

I believe this error is because I used my desktop username and it is stored as a repository somewhere (and I do not know where). Can anyone help troubleshoot what the issue is, and is there any other way to make a repository commit without moving the entire eclipse folder into a different location?

Comment: Hi @aestheticnoodle and welcome to SO. Could you paste the error text directly in the message rather than linking an image? Far more convenient for many potential helpers here.

Comment: There error is telling you that the location you’re choosing to create a new repo _already is one_. Perhaps you could choose a different location? Or add the already existing repo?

Comment: I have got a ios project source code  zip which is there in one git repository. I have saved it in my system. When I tried to create a new repository with that code in my github account, I got the error "this directory appears to be a Git repository. Would you like to add this repository instead". I dont want to add the previous repo in mine. I just need to add it as a separate one in my account. How will I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue because I still had files created by a previous Git repository in the folder. Example below:

[image: Github Screenshot]

I fixed this by deleting the files in the git folder. The git folder may initially be hidden, so you will have to fix this by showing hidden folders (right click in windows explorer and properties).

Comment: I can't find any .git folders on my computer but I'm getting this same error. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @Jarhead are you already show hidden directory? By default `.git` directory is hidden

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this image:

[image]

Sometimes if you get into your local repository folder you will not get the .git folder so you need to make the hidden folders  shown in the windows explorer in case you are using windows so buy deleting that folder the github desktop app or git bash or even visual studio wont show that warning again and you will be able to push that local repository to a new repository as you wish